# High precision thread synchronization

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have several objects of some class in which I run network data exchange. I need to start the network operations in threads as accurately as possible.This is in units of microseconds. By the time the work starts, the threads are already created and running. For synchronization i use static atomic variable. Objects created in main thread and then in other threads starts function on_start() of these objects.

```
class NetSender {
public: 
  static std::atomic_flag start;
  static std::atomic<uint8_t> net_sender_count;
  void on_start(){
    //... do some work
    net_sender_count++;        
    //waiting start of other 
    while(start.test_and_set())
        ;
    m_start_message = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    //do very important job here
  }
}
```

and somewhere in main() function

```
std::vector<NetSender*> senders[how_much_we_need];
//create senders items

std::vector<std::thread> senderthreads[how_much_we_need]; 
// for senders
senderthreads.at(i) = new std::thread(
                &NetSender::on_start,senders.at(i));
while(senders[1]->net_sender_count < how_much_we_need)
     ; //whait starting of all threads

senders[1]->start.clear();    //start job
```

(maybe there are some typos in my example but i hope the idea is pretty visible)

After that i compare m_start_message values and difference is from 10 microseconds to 100 milliseconds. Is there a way to reduce this difference to microseconds? Or may be there is some logical mistake(s).

Comment: Spawning a new thread is time consuming operation. You need to pre-launch the worker thread well ahead in your program so that the overhead in launch don't affect later. Then push your tasks (producer) to a std::queue ( or priority queue) protected by mutex. A consumer module can execute these tasks in the worker thread.

Comment: Is your problem about time exactitude, about ordering or both?

Comment: to Btc. Ordering is not important, threads do the same thing, but very important simultaneous execution of the task

Answer (score 0):

You want a conditional variable and a mutex combo.

Something like the following:

```
class NetSender
{
    static std::condition_variable _cvThreads; // threads signal this cv when ready
    static std::condition_variable _cvMain;    // main signals this cv after setting start condition
    static std::mutex _mutex;
    static bool _isStarted;
    static int net_sender_count;
    static int how_much_we_need;

    void on_start()
    {
        { // enter lock
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(_mutex);
            net_sender_count++;
        } // exit lock

        _cvThreads.notify_all();  // notify main thread that this worker thread is ready

        // wait for main thread to signal start
        { // enter lock
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(_mutex);

            while (_isStarted == false)
            {
                _cvMain.wait(lck); // atomically release mutex, wait for notify, then lock and continue
            }

        } // exit lock

        m_start_message = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        //do very important job here
    }
```

Then in your main thread

```
NetSender::_isStarted = false;

senderthreads.at(i) = new std::thread(&NetSender::on_start,senders.at(i));

// wait for all threads to get ready
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(NetSender::_mutex);
    while (NetSender::net_sender_count < NetSender::how_many_we_need)
    {
         NetSender::_cvThreads.wait();
    }
    NetSender::_isStarted = true;
}

NetSender::_cvMain.notify_all(); // signal all threads to start
```

Answer (score 0):

A few hints to get this working:

1) You might want to use a thread pool if you're going to be executing this several times.

2) You might not want to use wait/notify as this will introduce latency when descheduling/scheduling the threads. It might be better just to spin if the wait time is sufficiently short.

3) What you're looking for is a thread barrier. There are many known algorithms out there and you probably want to take advantage of them. If this is a one-time execution, a countdown latch might be favorable. Otherwise, barriers such as sense-reversing barriers can be reused. If necessary, use tree barriers to minimize the coherence traffic between cores.

A simple implementation might look  something like this (psuedocode, sorry, it's been a while since I've written C++):

```
void main() {

  // Create a barrier sufficient for syncing worker threads + main thread
  MyBarrier * b = new MyBarrier(num_threads + 1);

  std::thread threads[num_threads];

  for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; i++) {
    threads[i] = thread(onStart, &senders[i], b);
  }

  someWork();

  barrier->wait();

  ...
}

void onStart(NetSender *sender, MyBarrier * b) {

  doSomeWork();

  b->wait();

  doSomeMoreWork(); 
}

class MyBarrier {

private:

  std::atomic<int> count;

public:

  MyBarrier(int countdown) {
    std::atomic_init(&count, countdown);
  }

  void wait() {

    count.fetch_sub(1);

    while (count.get() > 0) {
      // spin
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried using the boost::barrier. It was possible to get a stable delay between the task starts in the threads (~37-40 microseconds), but that's too much. I need at least 3-5 microseconds. Is it possible?

Comment: The boost barrier uses wait/notify so your threads might be getting descheduled. Write your own barrier and spin when waiting to keep your threads hot, but don’t overschedule your cores in that case.

Comment: Thanks so much for your advice. I rewrote barrier and the delay is ~110-150 ns. It's good enough for my task.